# how do i reinsert a deleted record with auto incremented id in hibernate java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mysql-workbench

```
Contact contact7 = new Contact(7,"Jobs", "jobsatapplet.com", "CoffeeBeans", "0123456789");
contact7.setId(7);
//session.update(contact7);

Contact contact8 = (Contact)session.load(Contact.class, new Integer(7));
contact8 = new Contact(7,"Jobs", "javaatapplet.com", "Cupertino", "0123456789");
session.save(contact7);

// commits the transaction and closes the session
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This is my code, instead of reinserting record 7 it inserts a new record which increments the number of records with duplicate values.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can't insert a record again with the same primary key. Please describe what you actually want to do, since your code seems to be a big mess.

Comment: I don't know how your ORM works, but it looks like you need to change an existing `Contract` object instead of creating a new one.

Comment: i delete record 7 and 8 in my table and want to insert them again but can't seem to do it

Comment: i tried Updating it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but if it is to update an existing record, you can do this:

```
Contact c = (Contact)session.load(Contact.class, new Integer(7));
c.setLocation("Cupertino");
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This is, if your Contact class has a `setLocation()` method. Without the mapping and class files I can't be more precise.